# google Data Studio - send data back to google spread sheet or another location

Tags: looker-studio

We are working on marketing dashboards and reports and would like to add the ability for a user of the report to take action based on report data.

For example, if an item in a report needs to be re-ordered, or an ad needs to be paused; the user would click a link or a check box. That would ideally insert info into a google spread sheet, or cal a url that would log the data.

i know these are reports, and the purpose of reports is to view and analyze data. What i would like is to give the users the ability to act on the data in the report.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is when using tables (pivot or normal) you can hold down ctrl and select specific rows of your table. If you have other tables on that page, they will filter those rows you've selected in the other table, it works like a filter. You can then manually export those filtered table views to spreadsheet, saving the filtered data.
Or you could use filters in general, maybe with calculated fields (not sure if that works tbh) and if statements, so that you can filter your tables accordingly and then export them manually to spreadsheets using the three dots top right of each visualisation in datastudio.

Maybe you can find a workaround with this information to come closer to your desired situation.
Seeing as datastudio is just a reporting tool, I don't think there is another way to do this.